# How to achieve a login page which is different from the index with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our front-end framework is Angularjs 1.x,we need a login page,the layout of which is different from the index page. When users login，they can access to the index page.

So how to achieve this login page,and if they use the same ng-app? and how?

Comment: Hi are you using an Angular1 or Angular2 project?

What I do currently is render the display: css values of certain elements to invisible. You could also add them to your entry component and use other routes as children only. This might only be in the case of angular2